# Old canon smartbase MPC 200 all in one

Tags: printing, canon

How can install into Ubuntu 10.10 the old Canon Smartbase MPC 200 all in one drivers for printer and scanner?

Comment: You still using ubuntu 10.10 which is unsupported?? Why?

Answer (score 1):

- I would advise upgrading to a supported version of Ubuntu.
- Ubuntu (Linux in general) has generic drivers. This means drivers are shipped WITH the operating system and though those drivers might not support all available options for all printers most of us users do get the options we want.

So to install your printers search for the option `printers` and let it scan for your printer. It will most likely either find the printer, scanner and 7in1 card reader.

This should be the image (or a look alike of it) of the printer dialog (see the `add`?):

[image]

From there you just need to have the printer on and connected to your system for it to find it.